# Rails asset pipeline require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In rails to require a file in the vendor directory I know that I can do this in my application.j file.

```
//=require vendor/assets/javascripts/me.js
```

Am wondering how does one require the entire javascript folder in the vendor directory

Comment: Have you tried `//= require_tree vendor/assets/javascripts` ?

Comment: yeah and I got an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/include/.
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Try

```
//=require me
```

Vendor should be loaded by default

Assets are not namespaced

You might need to restart your dev server after adding to vendor